# I am from India, living in Netherlands. Do I need visa for Bulgaria?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, netherlands, bulgaria

I am an Indian passport holder. I live in Amsterdam and have Dutch resident permit which allows me to travel through Schengen countries.

Do I need a visa for visiting Bulgaria (Sofia) for 2-3 days?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indian embassy in Bulgaria says this

https://www.indembsofia.org/en/schengen-visa-holders-do-not-require-bulgarian-visa-to-visit-bulgaria/

> Holder of valid long term visas or residence permits issued by
>   Schengen Countries are allowed multiple entries and a period of stay
>   in Bulgaria for up to 90 days in any six-month period from the date of
>   the first entry.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=in&DE=bg&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=nl&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines based on live information from national governments:

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a residence permit
>   issued by Netherlands for a maximum stay of 90 days

So you do **not** need a visa - you just present your passport and residence permit card.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this document](http://www.mfa.bg/en/pages/109/index.html), you can enter Bulgaria without the visa. I would also call Bulgarian embassy to be sure.

Comment: BTW, you have cool portfolio